# Is the extern keyword necessary when referring a volatile variable declared in another C source file?

Tags: c, volatile, extern

I have two C source code files; one file contains a declaration like the following:

```
volatile unsigned char flag=0;
```

The other C file contains a reference such as:

```
extern unsigned char flag;
```

Is this correct and safe, or should the `volatile` keyword be repeated whenever referencing the variable? i.e.

```
extern volatile unsigned char flag;
```

Comment: Are you using a C or C++ compiler?  It doesn't seem like you should be using the `c++` tag here.

Comment: Now, if you wanted to know if the answer would be different between C and C++, that's fine.  Use both tags **and explain in your question in what way you care about both languages**.

Comment: The compiler, having only that *extern* declaration, and generating code to access the variable of course cannot know that it is supposed to be treated volatile.  The linker doesn't 'fix' that code, it is not its job.  You can't omit it.

Comment: it's useful to know the answer in both languages although my code base at the moment is C, which is compiled for an embedded system (ARM)

Comment: @b20000: Are you thinking of defining it in a C file and using it in a C++ context?  Just slapping on the `c++` tag is not enough to be useful, you actually have to explain what you want to know about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's not correct.

All declarations of the same variable need to use the exact same type, and `volatile` is part of the type (`extern` is not)

A good practice for checking `extern` declarations is to **put them in a header file that is also included in the compilation unit where the definition exists**.  Then the compiler will check them for correctness.

[Notice what happens if you do that on this example](http://ideone.com/fRO31C).

> ```
> prog.c:2:22: error: conflicting type qualifiers for ‘flag’
>  extern unsigned char flag; 
>                       ^
> prog.c:1:24: note: previous definition of ‘flag’ was here
>  volatile unsigned char flag=0;
> ```

Comment: I'm specifically avoiding putting anything about the compiler using optimizations that shouldn't be applied to volatile variables into my answer, in order to avoid the appearance that such a treatment is guaranteed.  If you want *that* behavior, make a pointer and cast away `volatile`.  But using incompatible definitions is undefined behavior, and can lead to far worse things that not respecting volatility.

Answer (score 4):

Some quotes from the C99 standard (emphasis added)

> 6.2.5/25 Type
>
> Any type so far mentioned is an unqualified type. Each unqualified
>   type has several qualified versions of its type, corresponding to the
>   combinations of one, two, or all three of the const, volatile, and
>   restrict qualifiers.  **The qualified or unqualified versions of a
>   type are distinct types**
>
> 6.2.7/2 "Compatible type and composite type"
>
> Two types have compatible type if their types are the same.
>
> ...
>
> All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have
>   compatible type; otherwise, **the behavior is undefined**.

If you think about your specific example for a moment, how would code that sees only the following declaration:

```
extern unsigned char flag;
```

have any idea that `flag` would need to be treated as `volatile`?

Also, unrelated to your question, keep in mind that `volatile` is usually not sufficient to handle access via multiple threads (in case that's what you're intending).

Comment: Is the term "One Definition Rule" used for C code the same way it is in C++?

Comment: @Ben: I don't think the C standard document uses the term (while the C++ standard does). But, I think the 'one definition' concept applies to C as well even if it's not explicitly used in the standard document.